# Why does mainjs.bundle not build with ReactNative 0.25.1

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, react-native, ecmascript-6

I had to disable `nvm` and install node-6.0.0 via brew in order to get a fresh, non-changed RN app on my iOS device with 9.3.1.

No matter what I do, the `mainjs.bundle` is not re-created. I switch my Schema from `Debug` to `Release` and change AppDelegate.m so the JS is read from the bundle and not the server. But in the moment I compile the app, I receive the following error:

`+ DEST=/Users/foobar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestSome-fpsorufynyrzmuceyzbnallqkbrd/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/TestSome.app
+ node /Users/foobar/tmp/reacttest/TestSome/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output /Users/foobar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestSome-fpsorufynyrzmuceyzbnallqkbrd/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/TestSome.app/main.jsbundle --assets-dest /Users/foobar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestSome-fpsorufynyrzmuceyzbnallqkbrd/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/TestSome.app
/Users/foobar/tmp/reacttest/TestSome/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:123
class CreateSuppressingTerminalAdapter extends TerminalAdapter {
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1`

To me it seem like, the 6to2 transpilation fails for some reason. If I comment out the class and remove it, where it's used, the next error comes up, complaining about the unknown keyword `const` somewhere.

If I build mainjs.bundle manually via:

`react-native bundle --dev false --minify --entry-file ./index.ios.js --platform ios --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle`

I can install the app on my device. But additional resources like images I `require()` are not bundled.

Can anyone tell me, where I can look for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to `node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh` and comment out this line:

```
if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" = "iphonesimulator" ]]; then     
  echo "Skipping bundling for Simulator platform"       
  exit 0;       
fi
```

This has been the only way I have been able to get this to work.

Comment: Thx Nadar. In fact that was not the full solution, but your hint led me there. There seems to be a problem with NVM. I did not install it via brew in order to make avn work. But `react-native.xcode.sh` seems to have a problem here, or my NVM installation is messed up. After I renamed `~/.nvm` the script properly build the bundle and cleanly includes all required resources.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for others having this issue, it has to do with Xcode running an old version of node, instead of the latest one.

**TL/DR**: Adding this line:

```
#nvm
[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh  # This loads NVM
```

to my `~/.bash_profile'` and restarting Xcode fixed the problem

.

**Long Version**: 
My nvm installation was messed up and Xcode was using node version `v0.12.7`

When I tried running `nvm use default` in `Xcode Project-->Build Phases--> Bundle React Native code and images` I noticed that it could not find `nvm`.
So adding the above line to my `bash_profile` fixed the problem.

I'm on OSX using `react-native 26`.